# Expected value for bit strings using indicator random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

So the problem states that let n>=2 be an integer, Consider a bitstring $b_1$; $b_2$;...;$b_n$ of length n, in which each bit $b_i$ is 0 with probability 1/2, and 1 with probability 1/2 (independent of all other bits).

Define the random variable X to be the number of indices i with 1<=i< n for which $b_i$$b_{i+1}$ = 0.

What is the expected value E(X) of the random variable X? [Use indicator random variables] The answer for this is ${3(n-1)\over4}$

**My first shot at this!**

I am particularly confused on how to properly use the indicator functions/variables. For this question, I'm assuming it should be  P(X=1) = 1/2 for the indicator variable.

There's also this constraint of bi*bi+1 = 0, so I'm assuming one of bi or bi+1 has to be 0. I'm not sure exactly how to properly assess the data given in the problem and apply the Expected value formula. It would be greatly appreciated if somebody could help me break down this problem so I have a better understanding :)

Comment: [mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). For starter, surround mathematical object with dollar signs.

Comment: oh thank you for this :) I was wondering how to edit the mathematical notations.

Comment: How could $(b_i\times b_i)+1=0$ if $b_i$ takes on the values $\{0,\,1\}$?

Comment: Hey, that's my bad. I had an editing error! Stilll getting used to this

Answer (score 1):

Let $$X_i = \begin{cases} 1 &, \text{ if } b_ib_{i+1}=0 \\0 &, \text{ if }b_ib_{i+1} =1 & \end{cases}$$

where $i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$.

We have $E[X_i] = \frac34$ since I just need one of the bit to be $0$.

Hence $E[X] =E[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i]= \frac34(n-1)$.

Comment: If you don't mind clarifying, how do you determine the X values of 0 and 1 for bi*bi+1? Also, how is the expected value calculated to be 3/4?

Comment: I let the event of interest be $1$.  That is when $b_ib_{i+1}=0$. $\frac34$ is the probability that $b_i=0$ or $b_{i+1}=0$. It can be either computed by inclusion exclusion or we can just subtract the complement.

Comment: Alright, and why are your bounds starting from n-1?

Comment: hmmm... i don't understand the previous doubt

Comment: Sorry, your summation for the expected value starts from i=1 to n-1. I was just wondering where the n-1 came from? Also, I am still not able to find the probability to be 3/4 for some reason.

Comment: compute $P(b_i=0)+P(b_{i+1}=0)-P(b_i=0, b_{i+1}=0)$.  Defining $X_n$ would be akward as we would have index out of bound. $X_n$ would depends on $b_n$ and $b_{n+1}$ but we don't have $b_{n+1}$.